# Object Oriented C will not compile

Tags: c, oop, constructor

I've been going through the first couple of chapters of this pdf on OOC: http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf

Now I tried to implement a String class. I used to files: main.c and new2.h.

This is main.c:

```
#include "new2.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    void * stringObject = new2(String,"a");

    printf((*stringObject).text);
}
```

and this is new2.h (including blanked out code, as I got rid of everything but the bare essentials I thought I need to make this work).

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct Class{
    size_t size;
    void * (* ctor)(void * self, va_list * app);
//  void * (* dtor)(void * self);
//  void * (* clone)(const void * self);
//  int (* differ)(const void * self, const void * b);

};

struct String{
    const void * mClass;//must be first
    char * text;

};

static void * String_ctor (void * _self, va_list * app)
{
    struct String * self = _self;
    const char * text = va_arg(* app, const char *);
    self->text = malloc(strlen(text)+1);

    assert(self->text);
    strcpy(self->text,text);
    return self;

}

static const struct Class _String ={
    sizeof(struct String),
    String_ctor

};



const void * String =&_String;



void * new2(const void * _class,...)
{
    const struct Class * mClass = _class;
    void * p = calloc(1,mClass->size);

    assert(p);
    *(const struct Class **)p = mClass;

    if(mClass -> ctor)
    {
        va_list ap;

        va_start(ap,_class);
        p=mClass->ctor(p, &ap);
        va_end(ap);
    }

    return p;

}
```

All of the functions in new2.h are taken mopre or less verbatim from the pdf link.
when I try to comile using gcc I get a warning. I'm dereferencing a void pointer, and an error that I can't call the string's text in main.c because my String is not a union or struct.

To be honest I find new2.h confusing. As I said I copied the functions from the pdf.
Here is what I think happens:

1. new2 is called. The argument String tells the computer to make a pointer to a Class struct and point it to the String struct already created in new2.h.
2. we allocate enough memory for a String object.
3. We call the constructor (String_ctor), and use the variable argument list to get the char argument, in this case "a".

My understanding is fuzzy, and this code doesn't compile. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make this code compile replace

```
 void * stringObject
```

with

```
 struct String * stringObject
```

Otherwise the compiler has no way to determine the address of .text field.

One reason for the methods of `struct String` return `void*` is to provide for inheritance. Only the calling program knows which subclass of `struct String` is being used.

The examples in the book can stay with `void * stringObject` because they use only the "public" interface of the String class and never get inside to access its private members.

Another way to print a string is to extend the class with a method that prints it out or to define a "friend" function.